# how to upgrade pepper robot from naoqi 2.5.10 to 2.9

Tags: pepper

Any way to upgrade naoqi 2.5 to naoqi 2.9 os for pepper robot 1.8a? cant reach softbank technical support with email. Would like to use qi sdk with pepper.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for Pepper 1.8a to be upgraded to run the new Android NAOqi version (2.9). But this process can't be completed by users - you'll need to [get in touch with your local Softbank Robotics support team](https://www.softbankrobotics.com/emea/en/support/pepper-naoqi-2-9/contact) for this.

The specific details vary so I can't say much more sorry.